# ASP Core WebApi File Upload Allow All Content Types

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm trying to create a file upload endpoint, but it looks like the only requests that get through have to specify `application/json` as the content type.  Here is what my endpoint looks like:

```
[HttpPost()]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateFile([FromBody] IFormFile contents)
```

I'm running .NET Core 2.0, and my startup.cs is pretty much just stock.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `[FromBody]` attribute indicates that that request body should be JSON (or another formatter such as XML, if you've enabled it). If you're uploading a binary, you should either use `[FromForm]` or just don't use an attribute at all.

Answer (score 3):

Your `FromBody` makes model binder think it should expect JSON formatted body. You either need to remove `[FromBody]` or put `[FromForm]`.